# Store encryption key in database

Tags: c#, encryption

I have two windows phone applications. First app sends data to server and second app(main) reads data from server. Datas are encrypted with Rijndael. Both applications have saved encrypted key in applications settings. But I'm thinking about storing encrypted key in DB. Is is good place for saving it in DB?

Comment: What do you mean with encrypted key?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you random generate your key you can't share it between two Apps, since two Apps can't access the same Storage on a Windows Phone. 
Meaning you would have to store the Key in an online Database, but then i don't understand why you even encript it, since the key can be accessed really easily.

If you always use the same Key you can hardcode it in your app and try to obfuscate it. Even though i don't think that really works.

If you generate your Keys based on the Phones Hardware, like it's mac adress you are rather save, but then it won't work with two different Phones.

I would generate your key based on a Username/Password that your Users choose, that way it's save and works on different Phones.

So, i would not save the Key in a DB.

If you by any chance talk about an Encryption Key only and use something like RSA that needs a different decription Key... just store both in the App, then you have less Sevr-Client traffic.

Comment: Now it is so, that user has to set up Key in both applications. App which sends data to server uses this key for encryption. App which reads data from server, uses this key for decryption. Problem is, when the user changes Key only in one application. After that I can't encrypt data and read them.

Comment: Add a Window that say, "your key doesn't match the key used to encript, please renew it" and then you open a textbox where the user can add the new Key aswell

Comment: Yes it is solution too. But I don't know compare the keys. I can only catch exception when I try to decrypt data with incorrect key.

Comment: When a user sends new data to the server, do you delete the old one or do you add the new one to the old one?

Comment: User doesn't send data. Application sends data. It's gps monitoring app. When background agent is executed, so it sends new position to the server. Old positions aren't deleted, and new position is added.

Comment: Your Server only stores the Data for the App, when the App adds Data with Key A and then changes to Key B and Adds Data again you have Data with Key A and Key B on the Server, then you get a Problem, so the User mustn't change the Key. Why would the User/App change the Key? Why don't you use the Password of the User as Key?

Comment: But create key from UserName/Password is good idea. If the user changes the password, I have to re-encrypt data in DB.

Comment: Correct, but should not be a problem, since you have the old password, just reencrypt the Data.

Comment: Ok thanks. I go for it.

Comment: But here is one problem yet. The both application have saved the encrypted key(from username/password) on phone. App A is main(reads data, create password, etc.) and App B sends data. If App A changes password the App B doesn't know, that password has been changed and it'll be still using Key created from old password.d

Comment: if your app can't decrypt the code, ask for password. That means you have to check if your app can decrypt code, to do so either use a Try method. If it always will decrypt but the content is wrong use a Header, for example always start your Transfer with an "1" and if the decrypted result doesn't start with 1 ask for password.

Comment: Maybe a bit longer Header just to be sure